# How to create SQL query for working hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sample data:

```
SELECT * from trips;

 trip_id | driver_id | pickup_timestamp    | dropoff_timestamp
---------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------
 1       | 1         | 2020-01-01 8:00 AM  | 2020-01-01 9:00 AM
 2       | 1         | 2020-01-01 8:30 AM  | 2020-01-01 9:30 AM
 3       | 2         | 2020-01-01 9:00 AM  | 2020-01-01 10:30 AM
 4       | 2         | 2020-01-01 9:30 AM  | 2020-01-01 11:30 AM
 5       | 2         | 2020-01-01 10:30 PM | 2020-01-02 12:30 AM
```

Write a T-SQL query that computes work hours when at least one passenger was in a driver's vehicle per each driver on specific date.

Query parameters:

```
date = '2020-01-01'
```

Expected result:

```
 driver_id | work_time
 ----------+-----------
 1         | 1:30:00
 2         | 4:00:00
```

Comments:

- Driver #1 worked from 8:00 AM to 9:30 AM without interruptions. That concludes to 1h30m work time.
- Driver #2 worked from 9:00 AM to 11:30 AM and also from 10:30 PM to 12:00 AM on that date that results to 2h30m + 1h30m = 4h of work time.

This is what I tried

```
select driverid as 'DriverID', 
    format(Max(dropoff_timestamp)-min(pickup_timestamp),'hh:mm') as 'Working Hour' 
   from trips where convert(date,pickup_timestamp)='2020-01-01' 
  group by driverid
```

but this query is not providing specific result DriverID Working Hour 1 01:30 2 03:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a query like below.

Also here's a [link](https://rextester.com/UTYPTM79349) to working demo.

**Explanation:**

initialsetfordate part defines a set of records which are from the desired date. It also additionally prunes down the dropoff_timestamp column to limit it's value to end of the day. We also get the next record's value using lead function.

Next continuous set uses the lead value found in previous set for each row and compares it with current drop off timestamp to use the minimum of the timestamps as higher time end range.

Finally we group by drivers' and sum the time difference for each record's dateranges.

```
 ; with initialsetfordate as 
 (
  select 
    driver_id, 
    pickup_timestamp, 
    dropoff_timestamp   = 
        case 
            when cast(dropoff_timestamp as date)<> cast(pickup_timestamp as date) 
            then cast(cast(dropoff_timestamp as date)as datetime)
            else dropoff_timestamp
        end, 
    new_dropoff_timestamp   =   
            ISNULL(lead(pickup_timestamp) over(partition by driver_id order by pickup_timestamp asc),dropoff_timestamp)
  from trips
   where cast(pickup_timestamp as date)='2020-01-01'

 ),
 continuousset as (
    select 
        driver_id, 
        pickup_timestamp, 
        dropoff_timestamp= 
            case 
                when dropoff_timestamp>= new_dropoff_timestamp
                then new_dropoff_timestamp 
                else dropoff_timestamp 
            end
    from initialsetfordate
 )
select driver_id,
 CONVERT(varchar(12), 
   DATEADD(minute,sum(datediff(mi,pickup_timestamp,dropoff_timestamp)),0), 114)  time_worked from continuousset 
group by driver_id
```

Comment: Done. As i am having less than 15 reputations and new on stackoverflow so, upvote on this answer will be displayed after 15 reputations.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution I created a SQL function that takes as parameter the driverID and it will return the total hours for each driver.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fn_getTotalHours 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @drive_ID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @TotalHours INT

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    --Gets the hour difference bettween the 2 dates
    --And return the sum for each driver
    SELECT @TotalHours=SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, pickup_timestamp, dropoff_timestamp)) 
    from trips
    Group BY driver_ID
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @TotalHours

END
GO
```

usage

```
select distinct driver_id,dbo.Fn_getTotalHours(driver_id) as TotalHours 
from trips
```